# Change build version - Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Is there a way to change the build version in Xcode 8?

I see the option below, but it won't seem to change it for me. It's stuck on "1.0.10" (what I last had it as before the new Xcode release).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value via a xcconfig file. Create a *Configuration Settings File* in Xcode with the following content

```
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 1.10.11
```

Then add this file in *Project Settings* | *Configurations* to the project or the desired targets.

**EDIT:** Btw. you can see where this value is currently set when you select *Levels* instead of *Combined* in the table header of the build settings.